# Writing a Lebesgue Measurable Set as a Union of a Measure Zero Set and a Countable Union of Compact Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to showing that using the notion of Lebesgue inner measure, i.e., using the fact that for a measurable set $E$, $m(E)=$Sup$\{m(K): K \;$is compact$\; \land \;K\subseteq E\}$, one can write $E$ as follows: $$E=A\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$$ where $m(A)=0$ and each $C_{n}$ is compact.

I've generated a sequence of compact sets $\{K_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with each $K_{n}\subseteq E$ and $m(K_{n}) \to m(E)$ by the definition of the supremum, but I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $C_n= K_1 \cup \ldots\cup K_n$. Then
$$m(K_n) \le m(C_n) \le m(E)$$
and since $m(K_n) \to m(E)$ we have also $m(C_n) \to m(E)$.  Now, since $C_n$ is an increasing sequence of measurable sets ( compacts) we have
$$m(C_n) \to m(\cup_n C_n) $$

Now, $\cup_n C_n \subset E$ and $m(\cup_n C_n) = m(E)$.

If we have also $m(E)< \infty$ we get $m(E\backslash \cup_n C_n) = 0$, so we can take $A=E\backslash \cup_n C_n$.

Otherwise, write $E= \cup_m E_m$, $E_m$ measurable, of finite measure. For every $m$ consider $L_m$ a finite union of compacts inside $E_m$, such that $m(E_m \backslash L_m) = 0$. Now take $A= E \backslash \cup_m L_m$.